# WYSIWYG editor in WP 3.2 plugin

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce, editor, wysiwyg

I've created my own WP 3.2 plugin. Now I want to put the WYSIWYG editor in it. I've tried the following code:

```
<?php the_editor(null, 'body', null, false); ?>
```

Then it's displayed. I don't know why, but the CSS doesn't look as it should look. Am I missing something? Should I include any CSS file?!

[image: weird tinymce]

Please look at the HTML/Visual buttons and the size of the content area.

Answer (score 1):

Look how I did it in my [Meta Box Class](https://gist.github.com/1748108):

```
$editor_settings =  array (
    'textarea_rows' => 8
,   'media_buttons' => FALSE
,   'teeny'         => TRUE
,   'tinymce'       => FALSE
    // a very minimal setup
,   'quicktags'     => array ( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,link' )
);
wp_editor( $content, $key, $editor_settings );
```

- `$content` is the already saved content you want to show in the editor.
- `$key` is the editor ID, it is used for the markup.
- For possible settings see `wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php` and the rather [short Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor).

Visual output:

[image]

You shouldn’t need a separate CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the following article: [Using the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor in your WordPress plugin](http://dannyvankooten.com/450/tinymce-wysiwyg-editor-in-wordpress-plugin/)